# Cross-posting on non-stackexchange sites?

Tags: discussion

The guidelines (see [this](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/cross-posting-to-stackoverflow-mathoverflow-and-related-sites) discussion) discouraging cross-posting duplicated questions seems to be limited in scope to multiple posts on SE sites only.  In light of a recent post [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/3021/how-to-obtain-fourier-series-coefficients-with-the-following-boundary-conditions), I realize that we haven't really had much discussion about how we should address cross-postings on websites outside the SE network.  I'm curious to hear the thoughts of the community on this.  Should we discourage it as well?

Answer (score 3):

From a practical standpoint, I think that discouraging cross-posting on sites outside of the SE network does us little good. There's no mechanism for us to enforce it. I think of SE as its own ecosystem; if we import knowledge from outside of SE into the SE ecosystem, it's a good thing. For cross-posters posting outside of SE, all I ask is that if they get a good answer on the non-SE site, they should then post that answer under their own question (as community wiki, because it's probably not "their" answer; it should be properly attributed), so that everyone who visits SciComp can benefit.

Comment: I think I've had the case of answering a question on a non-SE site, and finding that my answer got linked from a "cross-posting" by the same user here (either Math.SE or SO).  So I agree that should be a satisfactory approach, giving credit where due.