# Add "Cross-posting" as a standard reason to close the question

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Often, people ask the same question on multiple StackExchange websites. While this might be sometimes fine (a question did not get enough attention, the posts are cross-linked, some time has passed from the initial question submission - see [CS Discussion on Cross-posting](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156/cross-posting-to-stackoverflow-mathoverflow-and-related-sites)), there are a lot of obvious cases when a question is asked simultaneously at all StackExchange websites.

I suggest adding as a standard closing reason.

`Closing -> CrossPosting -> Enter a question link or numeric id`

or

`Closing -> Duplicate -> Enter a question link or numeric id` and allow for non-CompScience links.

[Example of CS question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/10475/how-to-find-out-if-it-is-possible-to-contruct-a-binary-matrix-with-given-row-and), for which one has to type a custom reasoning for off-topic for a question that is certainly crossposted to CS and SO.

Or does one has to flag such post `in need of moderator attention`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In such situations, it is advised **to flag the post for moderator attention** explaining the situation and giving the links to the cross-posted copies.

Notice, that not all cross-posts are created equally. If the cross-posted question

- searches for different inputs and point of views from different communities
- did not get enough attention in other community (1 day is obviously too short)
- contains links to the posts in other communities
- has a paragraph that tailors the post for a certain input from Computational Science SE

then it might be a completely legitimate cross-post that deserves an equal amount of attention and quality control as any other question in Computational Science SE.

The general verbatim cross-post of exact copies is certainly not OK.

The questions that are cross-posted in the violation of policies of Computational Science SE will be closed by moderators with **Needs details or clarity** reason and comment underneath linking to this policy:

> This question was identified to be posted at multiple Stack Exchange sites. Please, consult the [Stack Exchange guidance regarding such posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/383809) and [the discussion on Computational Science Meta](https://scicomp.meta.stackexchange.com/a/577/20688). In short, avoid the verbatim copies of the same question to multiple Stack Exchange sites without tailoring it to search for specific input.

In general, consult [General Meta guidance on cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/383809) and in case of questions or difficult cases, bring up the discussion regarding a particular question to this Meta.

Comment: Both the guidance and text are up for discussion, as I took the liberty of formulating it myself based on the votes, comments here, and on general meta.

Answer (score 4):

I've never seen a feature of this type on any other SE site, and I don't think one exists at all.  I think this is to encourage the OP's to modify their duplicate posts to fit the separate communities rather than to close such questions automatically.  I can certainly inquire further about it, but I'm less than optimistic about it.